# Polymorphic relationship vs STI vs Class table inheritance with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, polymorphic-associations, sti

There are three types of invoice items with following tables

1) **SubscriptionItems**,

2) **Prorations**,

3) **UsageItems**,

Those have the same attributes below

```
invoice_id
amount
stripe_invoie_id
```

However

only **SubscriptionItem** and **Proration**

```
period_start_at
period_end_at
```

and only **Proration** and **UsageItem** has

```
title
```

and only **UsageItem** has

```
uuid
account_id
description
```

To achieve this model I've been using polymorphic relation.

```
class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true
end

class SubscriptionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :invoice_item, as: :itemable
end

class UsageItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_one :invoice_item, as: :itemable
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :invoice_items
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :usage_items
end
```

For now it works.
However As far as I understand polymorphic should have `has_many` relation.
So this resides in the middle of `Polymorphic` and `STI`.
Because those three types of invoice items are **always** be subscriptionitem, proration, or usageitem.

It's hard decision that I could keep using this models (polymorphic with `has_one`) or should I use STI instead?
Or class table inheritance should be fit?

**EDIT**

I'd love to hear the reason why I could use some design.
Maybe those types **pros** and **cons**.

As far as I know,

If I apply STI

> That leads many NULLable columns, but RoR supports STI. So it's easy
>   to use.

If I apply polymorphic with has_one

> It stills the rails way but the original polymorphic definition is
>   different. It should have `has_many` relationship instead of
>   `has_one`. Also it's impossible to add foreign key.

Ref: [Blog post for STI to polymorphic](https://about.futurelearn.com/blog/refactoring-rails-sti/)

If I apply Class table inheritance,

> It's more efficient for relational database, but it's not rails way.

Ref: [Blog post for STI to class table inheritance](http://www.matchingnotes.com/class-table-inheritance-in-rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think STI with a hidden_field passing the appropriate value for each attribute that should determine the invoice type, could be the way to go here. It's **simple and efficient.**

Let's say you added a field called `:invoice_type` to your invoice model,

Then just loop through the items in an array like (Rough example):

```
<% @invoices.where(:invoice_type => "proration").find_each do |invoice| %>
   <% @invoices.where(:start_date => "#{@invoice.start_date}").find_each do |invoice| %>
         <!--Will only show the start_date of invoices where the invoice_type is propration. -->
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks maybe not invoice, but invoice_item?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Invoice_item!